# I'm writing a control to my aspx file from the aspx.cs file. Why am I getting this error when attempting to use the control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an empty HTML div in my aspx file:

```
<div id="containingDiv" runat="server">
</div>
```

My aspx.cs file is writing some HTML to the aspx file like this...

```
containingDiv.InnerHtml = "<uc:myControl runat='server' id='thisControl'/>";
```

Later in my aspx.cs file, the control is being acted on... sorry to be vague here but I'm not entirely clear about what it's doing I just know it's being used...

```
thisControl.somePropertyOrAction....
```

And I'm getting this error:

The name 'thisControl' does not exist in the current context.

Any ideas why? Many thanks.

Comment: dynamic controls cannot be called by line access.

Comment: This is a just string not a control at this time

Comment: Your property is rendered an returned to the client. it is not doing anything on the server with this code. Why would you want to do it the way you do? any spcecial reason?

Comment: I don't  currently have any other ideas? :-)

Comment: Why don't you just add the control straight in the `.aspx` file? Why try to add it from the code behind file? If you need to have it activated in some cases, and not active/visible in other cases, you can just use the `Visible` property on the control...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you load user controls dynamically in ASP.NET:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myControl control = LoadControl("~/myControl.ascx") as myControl;
    containingDiv.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

Comment: @OnwardsAndUpwards This is correct, but it means the control is a `dynamic control`. You will get into all sorts of trouble using it later on when you want the page to post back and the control is not there...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
and use it in your aspx.cs file by id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find the control in your html when you run the "being acted on".

Try something like this:

```
var control = containingDiv.FindControl("thisControl");
control.somePropertyOrAction = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to find it, I want to add it because I need it to only exist in certain circumstances... i.e.

if (some circumstance)
{
    create control in the html
} 

What Denis Wessels said sounds like what I'm after.
Thanks!